# How to make phone like scrolling in desktop?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, smoothing

I am trying to make a set a divs to be arranged in a row inside a parent container. User should be able to drag to scroll them sideways in any of the two directions. Effect should be like how we scroll vertically in Chrome for android where swiping up adds a force to the page that makes it scroll and the force decreases with time. This should be done without scrollbars. I searched but couldn't find any result. Closest i could get was [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9EWifQ5xqA&t=754s) video. But still here the scroll only worked while the mouse was moving. I want the force to decrease gradually and that too in a flexbox. Just like if you open developer tools and switch to mobile device and drag up.

Comment: My browser in my OS (Chrome on OS X) has inertial scrolling on a desktop by default. If you added your own, that would mess with what already exists. While there are ways to add your own (google "Inertial Scroll JS"), this sounds like a bad user experience in most cases. Generally you don't want to interfere with the built-in behavior of how the OS handles things, because that tends to make things like assistive devices work worse or not at all, and creates problematic edge cases. There may be reasons why it is worth it though....

Comment: thank you very much. 'inertial" keyword helps.

Comment: I looked at several examples for inertial scrolling libraries, and they were not good with my machine already having it's own inertial scrolling. The two features were fighting each other. So keep that in mind, and try to find a test machine that does have inertial scrolling.